# Data-frame in R without repetition of category

Tags: r

I have a data-frame which looks like this

```
> data
   Channels Sub.Channels Actual.Spend
1         A           a1          1.5
2         A           a2          2.7
3         A           a3          3.9
4         A           a4          5.1
5         B           b1          2.3
6         B           b2          1.2
7         B           b3          2.4
8         C           c1          2.3
9         C           c2          3.0
10        C           c3          3.6
11        C           c4          4.1
12        C           c5          4.7
13        C           c6          5.2
14        C           c7          5.8
```

However I want to report the data frame in the following way

```
> data

   Channels Sub.Channels Actual.Spend
1         A           a1          1.5
2                     a2          2.7
3                     a3          3.9
4                     a4          5.1
5         B           b1          2.3
6                     b2          1.2
7                     b3          2.4
8         C           c1          2.3
9                     c2          3.0
10                    c3          3.6
11                    c4          4.1
12                    c5          4.7
13                    c6          5.2
14                    c7          5.8
```

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `data$Channels [ duplicated (data$Channels) ] = ""` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or we can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[duplicated(Channels), Channels:='']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data$Channels[duplicated(data$Channels)] = ""
```

Comment: It returns with NA s instead of blanks